# Problem in installing library from github

Tags: libraries, compiler, fortran

Generally, while installing libraries like lapack, blas, I just run the makefile and then they get automatically installed. To link them with my gfortran compiler, gfortran -llapack or gfortran -lblas flags are enough to link them. But when I installed this slatec library using make, by giving the flag gfortran -lslatec, nothing happended and it gave error that cannot find slatec. How to install it properly?

https://github.com/Rufflewind/slatec

This is the library.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
make FC=gfortran all
```

builds the libraries in a *local* `lib/` directory:

```
$ ls lib/
libslatec.a  libslatec-dbvp.a  libslatec-sbvp.a  libslatec.so  libslatec.so.4  libslatec.so.4.1.1
```

If you want to link the library when building your own program, you will need to tell the compiler where to find it by supplying an additional library search path

```
gfortran . . . -L path/to/slatec/lib/ -lslatec
```

**or** copy the library/libraries to somewhere on the default library search path such as `/usr/local/lib` - the slatec Makefile provides an `install` target to do exactly that, as you can see by running `make -n install`

```
$ make -n install
install -d /usr/local/lib
install -m644 -t /usr/local/lib \
    lib/libslatec.a lib/libslatec-dbvp.a lib/libslatec-sbvp.a
install -m755 -t /usr/local/lib lib/libslatec.so.4.1.1
cp -P lib/libslatec.so lib/libslatec.so.4 \
    /usr/local/lib
```

so you'd do

```
sudo make install
```

To run programs that are linked against a new *shared* library, you may additionally need to run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

in order to update the dynamic linker cache.

Comment: After running the sudo make install, my program compiled. but ./a.out shows the error " error while loading shared libraries: libslatec.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Comment: @user157588 you may need to run ldconfig (`sudo ldconfig`) to add the library location to the dynamic loader cache